# ¿Por qué no me detecta el objeto JSONArray en java?

Tags: java, api, youtube

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde utilizamos la API de youtube para obtener determinados videos; claro, esta API nos da los datos del video en formato JSON pero a través de una URL donde nosotros accedemos y almacenamos en un string el contenido. Ahora entra en papel el objeto `JSONArray`: creamos una variable de este tipo donde nos almacena en un array la información obtenida de la URL y así obtener la información del vídeo que deseamos, pero las líneas de código de `JSONArray` es como si no estuvieran y no hace nada, ¿por qué?

```
public void search() {
    try{
        System.out.println("He entrado.");
        String keyword = getKeyword();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "");
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q="+keyword+"&type=video&key=AIzaSyCpFfwOoxXqzzajn3DWhgFs_jpMgw3UKv4").method("get", body).build();
        System.out.println("Paso del enlace: ");
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String respuesta = response.toString();
        respuesta = respuesta.substring(46,respuesta.length()-1);
        System.out.println("Respuesta: " + respuesta);
        
        URL url = new URL(respuesta);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ocurrio un error");
        } else {
            StringBuilder informationString = new StringBuilder();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            
            scanner.close();
            System.out.println(informationString);
```

Ahora viene la parte que no funciona: no da ningún mensaje de error de compilación, simplemente no la ejecuta o al menos parece eso porque no imprime nada en consola.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(informationString.toString());
System.out.println("jsonArray: " + jsonArray);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3);
System.out.println("Json: " + jsonObject);
System.out.println("Json 1: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(1));
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("videoId"));
}
```

Comment: Has revisado el error que tienes en la línea 45? Tal vez ese sea el motivo... en realidad no estoy seguro, porque no sé qué tienes en esa línea, pero es tan buen intento de adivinar tu problema como cualquier otro así que mientras no nos des un [mre], es lo mejor que podemos hacer. Cuando revises esa línea, usa el botón [edit] y añade el citado [mre] para poder ayudarte. Un saludo y bienvenido a SO, donde nos dedicamos a la programación y no la adivinación.

Comment: ya he adjuntado el código, perdón pero soy nuevo utilizando este foro

Comment: De hecho, _no es un foro_ :) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.